# How to handle null values in Sql Server like operator

Tags: sql-server, rdbms

I have created a stored procedure shown below it provides all the menus based on search of 'Text' and 'MenuType' columns.

I want to create it like if I pass  GetMenusbyTextandType '','-1' as paramters then it should show all the records of MenuMaster table. The problem is that I have some null values in 'MenuType' column, which are not reflecting in this proc.

```
Create proc GetMenusbyTextandType
    @Text nvarchar(400),
    @MenuType nvarchar(10)
as
begin
    SELECT * 
    FROM MenuMaster 
    WHERE Active = 1 
      AND [Text] LIKE '%' + @Text + '%' 
      AND MenuType LIKE 
             CASE 
                WHEN @MenuType = '-1' 
                   THEN '%' + ISNULL(MenuType, '') + '%' 
                   ELSE '%' + @MenuType + '%' 
             END
END
```

[image]

Comment: From the way your code looks I'm guessing sql server, but you shouldn't make people guess stuff like this. Please edit your question to include the relevan't rdbms tag and the table structure.

Comment: yeah its sql server

Comment: and the table? please add the table DDL and some sample data as DML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are over-complicating your sql. There is a simple solution:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MenuMaster 
WHERE Active = 1 
  AND [Text] LIKE '%' + @Text + '%' 
  AND (
      @MenuType = '-1' 
      OR MenuType LIKE '%' + @MenuType + '%' 
  )
```